# How to save pandas data frame in spark into amazon s3?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, pyspark

I would like to save pandas dataframe into a s3 bucket.
I tried below one which is already answered by somebody. But, It just gives me an error, `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'`.

---

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("s3n://id:pw@bucket")
```

---

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert the Pandas dataframe into spark dataframe and then you can use the spark csv package to save the file .

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("s3n://id:pw@bucket")
```

You can see  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436665/spark-converting-pandas-df-to-s3). Similar solution has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version 1.3 or earlier? In this case you just call `save` directly on the dataframe, i.e.

```
df.save(path="s3n://id:pw@bucket")
```

Comment: no, my version is 1.5 and I am using databricks cluster