# Spark converting Pandas df to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pandas, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Currently i am  using Spark along with Pandas framework. How can I convert Pandas Dataframe in a convenient way which can be written to s3.

I have tried below option but I get error as df is Pandas dataframe and it has no write option.

```
df.write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("123.csv");
```

Comment: maybe something like this would get you off to a good start: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html  Writing it to a buffer would work well with http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object.  Note, you don't have to write it to the hard drive just to write to s3.  In fact, both `to_csv()` and `put_object` seem to support buffers which would be very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are running this in Spark, one approach would be to convert the Pandas DataFrame into a Spark DataFrame and then save this to S3.

The code snippet below creates the `pdf` *Pandas DataFrame* and converts it into the `df` Spark DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create Pandas DataFrame
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
pdf = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Convert Pandas DataFrame to Spark DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.printSchema()
```

To validate, we can also print out the schema for the Spark DataFrame with the output below.

```
root
 |-- one: double (nullable = true)
 |-- two: double (nullable = true)
```

Now that it is a Spark DataFrame, you can use the `spark-csv` package to save the file with the example below.

```
# Save Spark DataFrame to S3
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').save('123.csv')
```